# Adding line to .First() during package installation

Tags: r

I'm developing R packages for my company of not so tech savy employees.

To facilitate the life of the users I'm thinking of having a set of scripts at a global location that can get sourced at startup in order to update and load relevant packages.

My idea is to have a script for each custom package that only gets sourced if that particalar package is installed. For this to work I need to modify the .First() function when the user installs the different packages, such that after packages A is installed:

```
.First() <- function(){
    source('script_to_package_A')
}
```

and if package B is then installed:

```
.First() <- function(){
    source('script_to_package_A')
    source('script_to_package_B')
}
```

Thus i am interested to add a line inside the .Rprofile file if .First() is already defined and the line is not in there already or, if no .Rprofile exists, create it.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

best wishes
Thomas

EDIT: Just to clarify - what I am looking for is a safe way to modify the .First() function that gets called during startup. That means that if a user already has defined a .First() function the additions will just be appended instead of replacing the old .First(). Preferably this addition to first will happen when a specific package is installed but this is not necessary. I'm fairly confident in what to add to the .First() function so this is not in question.

Comment: why not just run the function `update.packages(ask=F)` on startup so it will automatically just update everything (without a confirmation for each package)?

Comment: Also, you're missing the whole point of writing R packages. Why source a script from a package when that functionality could just exist in said package? Rather than `source` inside `First()`, just call the relevant functions in that package.

Comment: The reason is that I would like to have the possibility of changing what happens during startup at each installation - thus I figured that sourcing from a script I could change at my will would be a good idea...

Comment: What it be **so** bad to install all the packages on every machine? Of course, this depends on exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I would like a solution that would make it possible to use at different sites in different countries, so I would not be able to attend every pc - I'm not part of the IT department, just a researcher that wants to make my projects available to those that need them.

Comment: Also, I don't think I'm missing the whole point of writting R packages because I want a mean to control what happens during startup - be that updating packages or controlling which packages are loaded by default : )

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the easiest way to get what you want is to have a single package installed on all machines. If you can alter the `.First` function on everyones machine, then you can install a package.

Your `.First` function would be:

```
.First() <- function(){
    library(mypkg)
    run_mypkg_fun()
    ##Could also check for package updates
    ##update.packages("mypkg"...)
}
```

The function `run_mypkg_fun` can do all the checks you want, including:

- installing packages
- running different functions conditional on what's installed.

Comment: You don't want to install.packages inside of `.First` because installing packages requires restarting R which would then run `.First` which would then install packages which would then restart R which would...

Comment: @GSee - If you wrap the `install.packages` call in `if(interactive()){...}` you should be fine though.  Although I think you would need to explicitly use `utils::install.packages()` and have a repo specified.

Comment: @Dason, yes, unless the OP wants the package installed when starting an interactive session